# How to increase animator state speed with parameter through script?

Tags: unity, c#

Inside Update :

```
private void Update()
    
        if(startSpeedUp)
        {
            animator.Play("Walk Backward");
            SpeedUp();
        }
    }
```

Than in SpeedUp

```
private void SpeedUp()
    {
        if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            animator.SetFloat("Walk Backward", valueToLerp);
        }
    }
```

The problem is if I don't start playing the state in the Update animator.Play than the animation in the state will not start at all.

and if I set the State speed to 0 it will not do anything if I set the speed to 1 then there is no use for the parameter. and when I'm looking the animator controller I see that the parameter is not changing at all.

[image: Animator controller settings]

The parameter on the left Walk Backward should be increasing slowly by the script in the SpeedUp method but the parameter value is not changing.

I want to slowly speed up the state playing by using lerp to increase the Wal Backward parameter value.

So I guess I should set the state Walk Backward speed to 0 but than why the parameter value is not changing and how do I use the parameter with the state ? Where do I use the parameter in the State in the animator controller so it will affect the state speed ?

Comment: The actual problem here seems to be that the parameter does not change in the animation controller, despite there being code which is supposed to set it. The rest of the question seems to be a distraction. Possible explanations could be that this section of code is not executed at all, or that the `valueToLerp` is always calculated at zero. Unfortunately both seem to depend on a couple variables, and how these variables get their values is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is your `startSpeedUp` true for the full duration of the speed up? When/how is your `elapsedTime` zeroed?